# Custom HTTP header rsponce

Tags: http

I'm dealing with an api that needs me to provide a response to verify a webhook setup. According to their docs the response is expected to take the format of the following with a verify code posted to the end webhook url:

```
200 OK
example-code--9223-62bdcc222345
```

I've tried echoing out both 200 OK and the example code in the response page with the following:

```
echo '200 OK<br>';
echo $_GET['verify'];
```

however this generates a "invalid response" message which makes me think I need to provide the response in the http header, does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: done, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

When the documentation says you need to respond with `200 OK`, it likely means that it's talking about the HTTP status code. If this is the first time you heard of HTTP status codes, the most famous example is `404 Not Found`.

Since you're using PHP, the *default* status code is already `200 OK`, so just based on your example I think you should be able to change your code to this to make it work:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['verify'];
?>
```

Comment: Afraid that doesn't work, would it be possible to add the code to the http response header or is that impossible?

Comment: Can you verify your script is correct by opening it and adding your own (fake) verify code?

if it's all working as expected, i would say it's likely that the documentation is wrong, or you did a poor job transcribing the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so for anyone else facing this issue it turns out I needed to provide the response as a JSO string instead, i.e.

```
<?php
    $data_string = json_encode($_GET['verify']); 
    echo $data_string;
?>
```

and not

```
<?php
echo $_GET['verify'];
?>
```

Really hope this helps save someone some time.

Matt